# How to find last inserted id , transaction, commit, rollback from the following connection php/MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

**How to find last inserted id from the following connection php/MySQLi.**
I need to find last inserted row id to use that id as a foreign key in another table insertion. I want to use the following code as a database connection.
***how to do the transaction, commit, rollback feature in below connection.***

```
<?php
    class Database
    {
    private $db_server = DB_SERVER;
    private $db_username = DB_USER;
    private $db_pass = DB_PASS;
    private $db_name = DB_NAME;
    private $con = false;
    private $myconn = "";
    private $result = array();
    private $myQuery = "";
    private $numResults = "";
    public function connect()
    {
    if (!$this->con) {
    $this->myconn = new mysqli($this->db_server , $this->db_username , $this->db_pass, $this->db_name);
    if ($this->myconn->connect_errno > 0) {
    array_push($this->result, $this->myconn->connect_error);
    return false;
    } else {
    $this->con = true;
    return true;
    }
    } else {
    return true;
    }
    }
    public function sql($sql)
    {
    $query         = $this->myconn->query($sql);
    $this->myQuery = $sql;
    if ($query) {
    $this->numResults = $query->num_rows;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $this->numResults; $i++) {
    $r   = $query->fetch_array();
    $key = array_keys($r);
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($key); $x++) {
    if (!is_int($key[$x])) {
    if ($query->num_rows >= 1) {
    $this->result[$i][$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]];
    } else {
    $this->result = null;
    }
    }
    }
    }
    return true;
    } else {
    array_push($this->result, $this->myconn->error);
    return false;
    }
    }
    }
?>
```

Please help me to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php). Use:

```
$this->myconn->insert_id;
```

Comment: Can you please help me to do the transaction, commit, rollback feature in above connection.

Comment: You can easily find it here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php .

Comment: I tried like this 
public function autocommit($data)
    {
        return $this->myconn->autocommit($data);
    }
    public function commit()
    {
        return $this->myconn->commit();
    }
    public function rollback()
    {
        return $this->myconn->rollback();
    }

$db->autocommit(FALSE); Query 1
$db->commit(); Query 2 $db->rollback();      Now Query 1 executed successfully query 2 not working.

Comment: please help me to do the transaction, commit, rollback feature in above connection.